# Change size on image based on which key is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, keydown

```
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
    var c = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (c === 'a'){
        myImage.css("height", "+=2");
        myImage.css("width", "+=2");
    } else if (c === 's'){
        myImage.css("height", "-=2");
        myImage.css("width", '-=2');
    }
});
```

This is my code, I am trying to make the image 2 pixels smaller when the s key is pressed and 2 pixels larger when the a key is pressed. The code just doesn't do anything right now.

I'm getting a warning "use of getpreventdefault() is deprecated" but I don't think that is what is causing this.

Edit: I should mention the warning only appears after a key is pressed.

Comment: I don't believe you can use `-=2` as a CSS attribute like that.  You'll likely need to do the math (get the current size, subtract or add 2), then apply that specific width to the image.  As a side-note, I'd focus on setting EITHER the width or the height, and leave the OTHER property as "auto" - would simplify things dramatically.

Comment: An earlier version I had used var height = $(myImage).height() + 2; and  myImage.css("height", height); Still didn't work

Comment: So, in a test I have, it appears that the letter code is coming through as uppercase, even though I'm not specifying uppercase - see how I've altered the IF statements to make this fiddle work (and, BTW, your -=2 does in fact work): https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/5hzqe8o6/

Comment: Thanks! That was it!

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the width and height for each keypress. Update the width and height.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  var $img = $('#myImg'),
      key = e.which,
      height = $img.height(),
      width = $img.width();

  if (key === 65)
    $img.css("height", height + 2).css("width", height + 2);
  else if (key === 83)
    $img.css("height", height - 2).css("width", height - 2);
});
```

Check out the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/chris_scott718/h819ezba/5/) for a working example. If you need to calculate for different keys you can get the keycodes [from this sweet codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/mPgoYJ).